# How can the result of this summation be negative?

Tags: summation

I simplified a summation over a matrix to speed up an algorithm I'm writing. There's an error in my code though: I'm getting a negative value inside the square root. I can't tell if it's a programming error or if I did the simplification wrong so ... (forgive the syntax if it's bad ... this is more abstract than I'm used to writing...). Am I doing something wrong here?

Given a vector $M$ of length $N$:
$$sum = \sum_{N}{} M_{i}$$
$$avg = \frac{1}{N} * sum$$
$$sqsum = \sum_{N}{} M_{i}^2$$

**I am simplifying this expression:**

$$\sum_{N}(M_{i} - avg)^2$$

which expands to

$$\sum_{N}M_{i}^2 - 2*M_{i}*avg + avg^2$$

the summation can then be split up:

$$\sum_{N}M_{i}^2 - \sum_{N}2*M_{i}*avg + \sum_{N}avg^2$$

Extracting constants and using earlier definitions:

$$sqsum - 2*avg\sum_{N}*M_{i} + N*avg^2$$

And one more replacement with an earlier definition ...

$$sqsum - 2*avg*sum + N*avg^2$$

But avg can be expanded...

$$sqsum - 2*\frac{sum}{N}*sum + N*\frac{sum^2}{N^2}$$

Thus one of the middle terms cancels and I am left with

$$sqsum - \frac{sum}{N}*sum  =  sqsum - avg*sum $$

Have I done anything "illegal"?

Comment: Looks right to me.  Programming error maybe.

Comment: You did not do any mistake. It is a standard result to compute the variance. $E[(X -\mu)^2]=E[X^2]-\mu^2$. You may get negative because of MATLAB precision error.

Comment: The most likely explanation is simple human error. It's easy to make mistakes in calculation programs and hard to find them. I don't see anything wrong with the calculation in the post. If both are correct, then the only thing I can think of is rounding error, or that you're using a Pentium MMX.

Comment: Right, @Rajada overflow is also an issue. Numbers that are too large can become negative.

Comment: You haven't taken a square root in the formulas above. Where are you using the square root function in your code?

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes agree with you. Also sometimes happens with very small number. I also faced the same issue for couple of times.

Comment: @Rajada: Wouldn't $\mu^2$ be $avg*avg$ (instead of $avg*sum$)? I also thought of this formula but I got hung up on this point.

Comment: What are you programming in? Matlab , C++ ?

Comment: Yes. There is subtle difference because in $E[\cdot ]$ calculation there is a $1/N$ factor present outside. Which is not there in your case.

Comment: @EricStucky Rajada's equation is yours divided by $N$.  When $\mathsf E(X^2)$ is close to $\mathsf E(X)^2$ rounding errors can make the difference a negative

Comment: @RobArthan I omitted the square root for simplification of the post since it's not relevant to the potential error.

Comment: @Arjang I'm writing in c++

Comment: @DanielB. : Holy hell, how do you handle too big or small numbers, My stupid question is would it have made sense to the operations in e.g. Matlab and use them from C++ instead?

Comment: @Arjang The application is a (very simple) face recognition program. I was attempting to reduce execution time by simplifying a more complex algorithm, but from the look of it, my simplification is causing errors in the floating point math that result of the expression discussed here being negative. I'll have to look more closely at what's happening to see exactly why and if it's avoidable or if I need to do it the longer way. Interfacing with matlab is outside the scope of my project.

Comment: @DanielB. : Good luck, and thank you.

Comment: It seems this is actually a fairly well known problem, and there exist [Algorithms for calculating variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) to avoid it.

Comment: That looks like exactly the problem I'm having. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your equations.   Everything is as expected.

$$\frac 1 N \sum_{i=1}^N \left(X_i-\sum_{j=1}^N X_j\right)^2 = \frac 1 N \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 - \left(\frac 1 N\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right)^2$$

This is a well known result for **population variance** of data; which is basically what you are calculating.   It *should* always be positive, but rounding errors may occur in the RHS when the two terms are close; resulting in [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) when the loss of significance is greater than the difference.